# Excel: define a VBA function to shorten PERCENTRANK

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

In Excel formula become often very long and, consequently, unreadable. For example my formula looks like this:

```
=PERCENTRANK([vol];[@vol])-PERCENTRANK([pos];[@pos])
```

I would like to write just

```
=SCORE("vol", "pos")
```

How can I create a user defined function from the original worksheet formula?

Comment: You can create your own functions with shorter names, but then you will need to save your books on XLSM format. So compatibility could be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this relatively easily using VBA's `WorksheetFunction`. The most difficult part is actually getting the column of the `[@Range]` so you don't have to enter it - but that's not too complicated either.

In the VBE, create a new standard module and paste the following UDF:

```
Public Function SCORE(vol As Range, pos As Range) As Double

    ' We need to get the entire column of the table for each argument
    Dim tbl As ListObject, volRng As Range, posRng As Range
    Set tbl = vol.ListObject

    Rem -> Table columns are relative to the table - not the worksheet
    Set volRng = tbl.Range.Columns(vol.Column - tbl.Range.Cells(1).Column + 1)
    Set posRng = tbl.Range.Columns(pos.Column - tbl.Range.Cells(1).Column + 1)

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        SCORE = .PercentRank(volRng, vol) - .PercentRank(posRng, pos)
    End With

End Function
```

You have to keep in mind that table column numbers are not always the same as the worksheet's (if your table doesn't start in column A). So you essentially have to offset by the number of worksheet columns by subtracting the column from your arguments `vol` and `pos` from the column number of the first cell of the entire table `tbl.range.cells(1)`. Then you add one because columns numbers in VBA is "base 1".

You will still have to send the range of the individual cell - so using string arguments are not going to do well here. With all that being said, your new worksheet formula would look like:

```
=SCORE([@vol],[@pos])
```

or

```
=SCORE([@vol];[@pos])
```

depending on if you separate arguments using `,` or `;`.